# Read emails from txt file using python

Tags: python, arrays, file, email

I have a TXT file with emails, like:

```
From r Wed Oct 30 21:41:56 2002
Return ...
...
From r Thu Oct 31 08:11:39 2002
Return ...
...
```

I want to extract each email into an array, like:

```
["From r Wed Oct 30 21:41:56 2002 Return ...", "From r Thu Oct 31 08:11:39 2002 Return ...", ..., "From r ..."]
```

I am using python

```
 with open(self.file, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as data_file:
     lines = ''

     first_line = True

     for line in data_file:
         if line.startswith("From r") and not first_line:
             emails.append(lines)
             lines = ''
          else:
              first_line = False
          lines = lines + line
```

Comment: Based on what do you want to split the emails? each email has only 2 lines - From and Return?

Comment: Each email has n lines, but all start with 'From r'

Comment: @vitorcarvalho specific reason for extract in array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first line of every email begins with `From r`, we can loop over each line of the email, adding a new entry to the list of emails every time we see `From r`, and concatenating every line after that to the "current" email tracked by index `i`.

```py
emails = []
with open('emails.txt') as f:
    i = -1
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('From r'):
            emails.append(line)
            i += 1
        else:
            emails[i] += line

print(emails)
```

Outputs:

```
['From r Wed Oct 30 21:41:56 2002\nReturn ...\n...\n', 'From r Thu Oct 31 08:11:39 2002\nReturn ...\n...\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
emails_list = []
email = ""
with open("full/path/to/file", "r") as f:
    email += f.readline()
    for l in f.readlines():
        l = l.strip()
        if not l.startswith("From r"):
            email += " " + l
        else:
            emails_list.append(email)
            email = l
    else:
        emails_list.append(email)

print(emails_list)
```